# why does mmap fail?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

I'm given a physical address, specifically `0x000000368d76c0`. I'm trying to `mmap` it into my program. The code that I'm using is

```
void *mmap64;
off_t offset = 0x000000368d76c0;
int memFd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
if (-1 == memFd)
  perror("Error ");

mmap64 = mmap(0, sizeof(uint64_t), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, memFd, offset);
if (MAP_FAILED == mmap64) {
  perror("Error ");
  return -1;
}
```

For some reason when I run this code I get a failure on `mmap`. Specifically it says `Error Invalid argument`. I'm pretty sure it is because of the `offset` value, but I don't know what is wrong with it.

I would appreciate any help on it.

Comment: Do you mean `address` by `adddress` in the arguments of `mmap()`?

Comment: @MikeCAT I mean the `offset` argument.

Comment: [mmap(2) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) says "`offset` must be a multiple of the page size as returned by `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`". What is the value in your system? Reference: [sysconf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)

Comment: @MikeCAT - why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @4386427 Because I haven't get the value yet.

Comment: @MikeCAT - well - respect... But still, your comment is the answer :-)

Comment: @MikeCAT The return value of `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` is `4096`. So you were correct. I'm not mapping on the page boundary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [mmap(2) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html),

> `offset` must be a multiple of the page size as
>   returned by `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`.

When the page size is 4096 (a page size used in x86 CPU), `0x000000368d76c0` is not a multiple of 4096 and will be considered as invalid.

For that reason, you will have to adjust the offset.